# Showing ellipsis in GroupBox, when text is too long?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

RadioButton and CheckBox have WrapText property. When it is enabled, a text, which is too long for a control, gets wrapped. When it is disabled, ellipsis appears at the end.

Label has AutoElipsis property that does the same thing, except it has to be enabled for ellipsis to show.

How to force the same behavior in GroupBox?

Comment: Simply change `GroupBox.Text` when `GroupBox` is resized. See [MeasureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xe5hazb.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There you go, I created custom control for you. Use it instead of GroupBox, you can also enable/disable AutoElipsis through designer properties or in code.

```
public class ElipsisGroupBox : GroupBox
{
    private string _tempText;
    private bool _isElipsisOn;

    public ElipsisGroupBox () : base()
    {
        _tempText = string.Empty;
        _isElipsisOn = false;
    }

    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnResize(e);

        if (this.AutoElipsis)
        {
            _tempText = base.Text;
            if (_tempText.Length == 0 || base.Width == 0)
                return;

            int i = _tempText.Length;

            string textToCheck = _isElipsisOn ? _tempText : _tempText + "...";

            _isElipsisOn = false;
            while (TextRenderer.MeasureText(textToCheck, base.Font).Width > (base.Width - 14))
            {
                _isElipsisOn = true;
                textToCheck = base.Text.Substring(0, --i) + "...";
                if (i == 0)
                    break;
            }

            if (_isElipsisOn)
                _tempText = textToCheck;
        }
    }

    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return this.AutoElipsis && _isElipsisOn ? _tempText : base.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.AutoElipsis && _isElipsisOn)
                _tempText = value;
            else
                base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    public bool AutoElipsis { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I think after any assignment of Text, the OnResize should be called, otherwise the elipsis will not show up if the text is too long (only after an additional resize).